# Character not following bones in pose mode

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, pose-mode

I have weight painted my character, and the bones were moving perfectly fine in pose mode, but after some time when I came back to animate it, the bones have stopped following the character. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Hi, it is not possible to help you without many more info, or better a sample file (you can share it here easily using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: @m.ardito hey, thanks for replying, the problem was that i incidentally applied the armature and that caused my character to have no effective movements when i move the bones in pose mode. thanks again!